# How to ignore system/hidden directories when using os.listdir?

Tags: python

When I am using `os.listdir()` to analyze a content of a zip file, I often get unexpected system directories like `__MACOSX`. I know I just can write a function to ignore `__MACOSX` but I need a more sophisticated solutions . I need all hidden directories from whatever operating system (MAC OS, windows or linux) to be automatically ignored.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Well, if you use `glob` instead of `os.listdir` it shouldn't include hidden directories by default... but it's a different system call

Comment: `__MACOSX` doesn't start with `.`, so `glob` won't ignore it by default.

Comment: `s[0] in ('_', '.')` is what i would do...

Answer (score 0):

Hidden Files start with ".", so you can remove filename that starts with "."

```
import os
for f in os.listdir('Your_path'):
    if not f.startswith('.'):
        print(f)
```

Comment: the problem is , this solution doesn't handle some hidden directories like `__MACOSX`...